# How to speed up keras model prediction inside a loop for tensorflow 1?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a trained `keras` model which I call interactively to predict on new data inside a loop.

According to the discussion in the link below it should be possible to speed up model evaluation by switching from `model.predict()` to `model(...,training=False)` but the solution is for `TF2` not `TF1`.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40261

I tried running a very similar example but got opposite results:

```
x = Input(shape=(1, 1))
xx= Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=xx)
import time
t = time.time()
i = 0
while i<100:
    model.predict(np.zeros((1, 1, 1)))
    i += 1
print(time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
i = 0
while i<100:
    model(np.zeros((1, 1, 1)), training=False)
    i += 1
print(time.time() - t)
```

The first one is consistently faster than the second one for me, which it should be the opposite.

I am using `tensorflow` version `1.12.0`. Is there any minimum working example code for how to efficiently run a `keras` model inside a loop interactively and in evaluation mode only for `TF1`?

Comment: You stated in your question that this solution is for TF2, not for TF1. Why did you assume that it would work for TF1 as well? If you want to speed up the evaluation, just use a bigger batch size.

Comment: Already using largest batch size possible. But there's still an overhead that could be removed. It's way too slow inside a loop.